# Adding Chinook database to MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am a new learner in SQL and I need your help.
I need to use Chinook database to my exercise and I do not know how to add, please guide me
This is my Chinook database https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/

Thanks!

I opened the application and tried to find where I can add the data in this app but did not succeed. I wonder I will add the data in this application or I have to add in another place. I am using Mac and not familiar enough in setting up the program.

Comment: MySQL Workbench is a tool for MySQL databases. The sample data you're using is an SQLite database. You can't just 'add' it. These are two different products. Have you installed the MySQL server? If not, MySQL Workbench has nothing to work with.

Comment: I need to use SQLite database in MySQLWorkbench. Yes, I installed MySQLWorkbench and just do not know how to convert SQLite database to MySQLWorkbench.